# Populate a select box with all the numbers up to current stock

Tags: php, jquery

I have two questions:

1) Say if I have a database like this:

```
Name             Stock
Prada            10
Armani           20
Gucci            25
```

How do I populate each select box with say `1-10`; `1-20`; and `1-25`

This is my code:

```
<?php
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print
    "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>"..
       "<div class='form-group'>".
          "<label for='sel1'>Select list:</label>".
          "<select class='form-control' id='sel1'>".
            "<option>$row["Stock"]</option>".
          "</select>".
        "</div>".
        "<button id='button" class='btn btn-success add'>Add to basket</button>".
    "</div>";
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        // HOW DO I GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECT BOX SELECTED HERE?
    });

</script>
```

Also, how do I get the value from the selectbox?

Comment: Problem here : `$row["Stock"]` try to concatenate your var. And at 3rd line, you have `..` ...

Comment: Inside double quoted string you should use vars inside curly brackets as `{$row["Stock"]}`

Answer (score 0):

From what you've mentioned, it seems like you want to fetch the select box options and loop through them. In that case, only the option should be within the while loop.

And, I'd suggest you to keep your code clean and write your HTML and PHP codes separate rather than printing your HTML within PHP.

```
<?php  /* Other PHP code */ ?>

 <div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>
   <div class='form-group'>".
      <label for='sel1'>Select list:</label>
      <select name="stock" class='form-control' id='sel1'>

      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

          <option value="<?php echo "1-".$row["Stock"]; ?>">
              <?php echo "1-".$row["Stock"]; ?>
          </option>

      <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button id='button" class='btn btn-success add'>Add to basket</button>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please do this within my php code (my current code) please. I am finding it hard to follow this

Comment: I think I've written the entire code except the button. Let me add that. But, which part are you finding it difficult to follow?

Comment: well you are not printing it. can you modify it in my code please because I am priniting everything at the moment - it is easier for me to follow that way

Comment: I don't want the php echo inside option value - just could you please put your code into mine

Comment: also what about getting the value from the select box?

Comment: also does this give a LIST so in other words `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` ??